Streaming the react js script rather than hosting publicly?
Let me first preface by saying I am not a frontend dev in the slightest. I am working on a solution for my employer where the IP is very sensitive and cannot be hosted publicly, even its representation. This puts me in a bit of a quandary in how to proceed and perhaps there is someone in SO that might be able to point me in the right direction.
I have a React frontend that connects to a socket api. The frontend currently has no sensitive IP so having its .js file hosted publicly is no issue. We now however have a requirement of adding in a view or frame in that static website to display some algorithm inputs and outputs that cross into the sensitive IP realm and if it was able to be viewed by just downloading the .js file it could potentially be reverse engineered by our competition.
What I was wondering is if there was a way or pattern to have the initial site load, connect to the socket api and then stream the other view/frame's script to it after a successful authentication/authorization. We have everything wrapped up behind Okta/Auth0 so we can effectively lock things down with our tokens but now the issue lies with just transmitting or making specific bits accessible. Id prefer to keep away from server side rendering but I am not fully adverse to it if it is the only option.
Appreciate any help or guidance.

So why not proxy all these requests, calculations, algorithms through a backend? I.E. api calls? Hide away all the complex logic / IP you don't want exposed there, and have your frontend consume that API

The logic would be in the backend, but any visual representation could be backwards engineered by a competitor so any field names, button names, titles etc would be big clues in this competitive market.
